# css not applying to textbox in Jquery Validations

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, validation

Hi iam trying to validate empty text boxes using jquery. i just wanted to change color of text box which is not valid.

Iam trying with following code.

```
<td width="10%" class="td">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemark" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="remarks"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="imgSubmit" Text="SUBMIT" OnClientClick="validate()" ClientIDMode="Static" />
$("#imgSubmit").click(function validate() {
    var name = $("#<%=txtRemark.ClientID %>").val();
    if (name == "") {
        alert("Validation working");
        $("#txtRemark").css({
            "border": "1px solid red",
            "background-color": "#FFCECE"
        });
    } else {
        alert("Welcome: " + name);
    }
});
```

But this CSS is not getting applied to text box.
I have included jquery-1.9.1.js, jquery-ui.css ,jquery-ui.js,jquery-1.7.2.min.js.

Iam getting alert working., but CSS is not applying, I am i wrong somewhere.., Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **Suggestion :** use `.on` instead of `.click`

Comment: change `function validate() ` to `function()`

Comment: NO use., using click, its going inside and getting alert. just now used .on its not working.

Comment: try to `alert name` like `alert(name);`

Comment: @RohanKumar i have alert(name) is showing empty alert. which means condition is satisfed, but CSS is not getting applied to text box

Comment: @pink check my answer once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<%=txtRemark.ClientID %>` in place of `txtRemark` when you applying `css` and remove `OnClientClick="validate()"` from your button control like,

```
<td width="10%" class="td">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemark" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="remarks"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="imgSubmit" Text="SUBMIT" OnClientClick="validate()" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Wrap your code in `document.ready()` like,

```
$(function(){
    $("#imgSubmit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#<%=txtRemark.ClientID %>").val();
        if (name == "") {
            alert("Validation working");
            $("#<%=txtRemark.ClientID %>").css({ // use <%=txtRemark.ClientID %> here also
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background-color": "#FFCECE"
            });
        } else {
            alert("Welcome: " + name);
            $("#<%=txtRemark.ClientID %>").removeAttr('style'); // remove applied css
        }
        return false;// use to prevent reload page
    });
});
```

Otherwise you can try `html controls` instead of `asp.net` like,

```
<td width="10%" class="td">
    <input type='text' id="txtRemark" class="remarks" />
</td>
<input type="submit" id="imgSubmit" value="SUBMIT" />

$(function(){
    $("#imgSubmit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#txtRemark").val();
        if (name == "") {
            alert("Validation working");
            $("#txtRemark").css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background-color": "#FFCECE"
            });
        } else {
            alert("Welcome: " + name);
            $("#txtRemark").removeAttr('style'); // remove applied css
        }
        return false;// use to prevent reload page
    });
});
```

Comment: CSS color change is not lasting for longer time, its just blinking and going away., i want that color change to be there untill he fills some text

Comment: i want to remove that css in else part , untill then i want css to be applied, but its just for seconds

Comment: Is your page get refreshed after clicking on button? If yes, then use `return false;` in your `click()` see my updated answer

Comment: In else part how do i remove CSS again??? WHen he enters text it must not be red color

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use named function within the click method but instead use that as callback.

```
function validate(){...}

$("#imgSubmit").click(validate);
```

Or just replace named function

```
$("#imgSubmit").click(function validate() {
```

with

```
$("#imgSubmit").click(function(){
```

Comment: just just check my edited question. Iam using that validate in button click

Comment: if i use click(function(){ i think its no use to write onClientClick on button??

Comment: Sorry Still CSS is not getting applied to my textbox. Iam just getting alert.

Comment: test it,by editing the if (name == "hello") and then type hello in the textbox then submit, also alert the name like this alert(name); to see if the hello is the value of the textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
    <td   width="10%" class="td">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemark" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="remarks" ></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="imgSubmit" Text="SUBMIT" OnClientClick="validate()" ClientIDMode="Static" />

       $("#imgSubmit").click(function () {

            var name = $("#<%= txtRemark.ClientID %>").val();
             if (name == "") {  
                 alert("Validation working");  
                $("[id$='<%= txtRemark.ClientID %>']").css({
                                  "border": "1px solid red",
                                  "background-color": "#FFCECE"
                 });

             }
             else {
                 alert("Welcome: " + name);
             }
return false;

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using the CssClass instead of the ID of the asp:Textbox and also remove the colon in the javascript, like this

```
$(".remarks").css("border", "1px solid red");
$(".remarks").css("background-color", "#FFCECE");
```

Comment: Yes its coming but not lasting for longer time.., its just blinking and going...What do i do to last for loner time untill i remove it in else part